# $C - (A \Delta B) \subseteq (A \cap C) \cup (C - B)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How to prove the following set theory identity:

If $A, B, C$ are sets, prove that $C - (A \Delta B) \subseteq (A \cap C) \cup (C - B)$, where symbols "$-$" denotes the set difference and "$\Delta$" symmetrical difference, respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x \in C \setminus(A \Delta B)$ means that $x$ is in $C$ but not in the symmetric difference of $A$ and $B$. So $x$ belongs either to $C$ and $A \cap B$, or to $C$ and not to $A$ and not to $B$. In the first case, $x$ belongs to  $A$ and $C$ that is $A \cap B$, and in the second case to $C$ and not to $B$ that is $C \setminus B$.

Finally, $x$ belongs to $(A \cap C) \cup (C \setminus B)$ as desired.